# Programatically set customer group price - Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: product, price, model, group-price

I am trying to set customer group specific price for product like this:

```
// Parse group prices
$groupPrices = array();
foreach ($productInfo->Prices as $groupPrice) {
    $groupPrices[] = array(
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => intval($groupPrice->GroupId),
        'price' => floatval($groupPrice->GroupPrice)
    );
}

// Load product id by sku
$productId = (int)Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($productInfo->Sku);
if (!$productId)
    throw new Exception('Product does not exists by SKU: '. $productInfo->Sku);

// Load product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($productId);

// Clear any previous group prices
$product->setGroupPrice(null);
$product->save();

// Save new group prices
$product->setGroupPrice($groupPrices);
$product->save();
```

When this code runs, I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '86-1-0-10.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`,
>   `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `website_id`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.

If a product already has "Tier Prices" defined, updating customer group prices somehow causes that error I reported above.

So, this is how I have solved it and it's working:

```
// Parse group prices
$groupPrices = array();
foreach ($productInfo->Prices as $groupPrice) {
    $groupPrices[] = array(
        'website_id' => 0,
        'cust_group' => intval($groupPrice->GroupId),
        'price' => floatval($groupPrice->GroupPrice)
    );
}

// Load product id by sku
$productId = (int)Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($productInfo->Sku);
if (!$productId)
    throw new Exception('Product does not exists by SKU: '. $productInfo->Sku);

// Load product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($productId);

// Clear any previous tier prices
$oldTierPrices = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_backend_tierprice')
    ->loadPriceData($productId, null);
$product->setTierPrice(null);

// Clear any previous group prices
$product->setGroupPrice(null);
$product->save();

// Save new group prices
$product->setGroupPrice($groupPrices);
$product->setTierPrice($oldTierPrices);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The composite key `E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087` consists of `entity_id`,`all_groups`,`customer_group_id`,`qty`,and `website_id`, in that order.

When you're saving `$product` with ID 86, there's already a tier price record with that composite key. This probably means that your "clearing previous group prices" is not working or you're creating `$groupPrices` incorrectly. I would first check `$product->setGroupPrice(null); $product->save();` is actually working. Also, I don't think you need to `save()` twice.